# KDB+/Q: implementation of numpy random choice, with probability distribution?

Tags: kdb

What is a canonical method to implement [numpy random choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) in kdb+/q?
Specifically how would one replicate the following selection

```
np.random.choice(5, 3, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])
```

whereby a probability distribution is provided. roll, deal and permute don't seem to take into account a probability distribution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think a hacky way of doing it might be this:

```
q){[n;k;p]k?raze p#'til n}[5;3;1 0 3 6 0]
3 2 3
```

Where instead of giving a list of probabilities, you give a list of integers representing proportions (but would still represent probabilities).

I imagine there's a more *canonical* way of doing it though.

I think this works if you need probabilities though:

```
q){[n;k;p]k?raze ("j"$p*10 xexp max count each("."vs'string p)[;1])#'til n}[5;3;0.05 0 0.3 0.65 0]
2 3 3
```

Again, very hacky.

EDIT: as user20349 says in the comments, you can use an overload of `where` to do the above with one less argument:

```
q){[k;p]k?where p}[3;1 0 3 6 0]
3 0 3
q){[k;p]k?where("j"$p*10 xexp max count each("."vs'string p)[;1])}[3;0.05 0 0.3 0.65 0]
3 3 3
```

Comment: Have a look at the where operator on an integer list. ```where[p]``` is doing what you need, I think.